# Backup sshfs volume via Time Machine on macosx

Tags: macos, time-machine, sshfs, macfuse

Is it possible to mount a filesystem via sshfs on my mac and have
time machine back that up to external disk?

Time machine does backup any other external drives to its dedicated
external drive so this problem reduces to having TM recognize the sshfs
volume. How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you try it and post your results back? Maybe it will simply work...

Answer (score 0):

You can mount SSHFS with *MacFUSE*.

In order to back it up, it's a little tricky but there were other people with the same problem (most related to NFS); I've read that *Time machine* needs the support to hard links, so the solution is to use a compatible format: you have to create (check `hdiutil`'s man page) a sparse disk image or a sparsebundle (check `tmutil` if you have OS X 10.7+).